# Best way to combine multiple files into a single XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I have a collection of files that I'd like to be able to combine into a single XML, according to a specific schema.

I'm thinking about something like using XSLT with a custom `XmlResolver` (C# / .NET), although I'm not sure if that would give me enough control over how the XPath expressions in the XSLT are parsed to be able to direct certain expressions to certain files.

The files to be combined will be XML fragments. In general, the entire fragment will be incorporated into the XML destination, though it would be nice to have the option of just incorporating certain fields.

Example:

Starting with three fragment files:

```
one.txt: contains <One>Number One</One> [or maybe just "Number One"]
two.txt: contains <Two>Number Two</Two> [or "Number Two"]
three.txt: contains <Three>Number Three</Three> [or "Number Three"]
```

I want to combine one.txt and two.txt into the following, while ignoring three.txt:

```
<Numbers>
  <One>Number One</One>
  <Two>Number Two</Two>
</Numbers>
```

I'm looking for a descriptive approach, not custom code, since there can be many different fragments and many different combinations.

I know the code below won't work, but something like this:

```
<Numbers>
    <xsl:value-of select="mine:one.txt/One" />
    <xsl:value-of select="mine:two.txt/Two" />
</Numbers>
```

The XML fragments can be complex, so a simple file-merge isn't enough. I will probably want some form of XPath / XQuery to extract the relevant pieces.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you have the schema why not just create a DataTable and import and assign your fragments using ADO.NET row / column features then export out to XML.

Comment: Is this for a once-off process or a core business process that occurs often?

Comment: Regarding DataTables: how to I describe which files get placed into which parts of the final document? There are too many different files and combinations to do it using code alone.

Comment: This is a core business process that will occur often, over potentially millions of different files. A given end-result XML file many contain an arbitrary combination of the available fragment files.

Comment: You could write a bespoke system that would do the job, but if it is a core business process maybe you should start looking at an Integration engine such as Microsoft BizTalk Server, Mulesoft (open source) or similar.  (Full disclosure, I'm a BizTalk developer in New Zealand)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm reasonably familiar with BizTalk, and unfortunately it wouldn't be appropriate for this system. In this case, all of the inputs and outputs are on the same machine -- I'm basically trying to generate different views into the same underlying data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
<Numbers>
    <xsl:copy-of select="doc('mine:one.txt')/One" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="doc('mine:two.txt')/Two" />
</Numbers>
```

I don't think you've explained why you think you might need a custom XmlResolver, but if you do, then it's no problem

Comment: I wasn't aware of that syntax; may be just what I was looking for! Regarding the custom XmlResolver, the "files" aren't really files; they are records in a database, hence the custom scheme name. I'd also like to do my own XPath processing. Do you know if XmlResolver provides access to the XPath queries, too, or just the URIs?

Comment: The XmlResolver takes a URL as written in your query, e.g. mine:one.txt, and returns an XML document. It doesn't have access to the XPath query, only to the URL. (Note: I used the doc() function which is XSLT 2.0, if you are using XSLT 1.0 it should be document().)